# How can I see the PostgreSQL column type from a RowDescription message?

Tags: postgresql, types, column-types

I'm implementing a driver to PostgreSQL and gets an [`RowDescription`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/protocol-message-formats.html) message and a few `DataRow` messages in response to a database query. But how do I get the type for the columns returned? E.g. the first column should be an `int` and the second an `varchar(20)`.

Here are some printouts from `RowDescription`:

```
[RowDescription] 2 rows
[Row] id
tableObjId: 16393
attrNr: 1
objId: 23
dataTypeSz: 4
typeModifier: -1
formatCode: 0
[Row] name
tableObjId: 16393
attrNr: 2
objId: 1043
dataTypeSz: -1
typeModifier: 24
formatCode: 0
```

and for the `DataRow`:

```
[DataRow] 2 columns
data: 2
data: Jonas
[DataRow] 2 columns
data: 76
data: Anders
```

Any suggestions? Is this anything I have to lookup in any systemtables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objId` is the reference to `pg_type.oid` for the column type. 23 is `int4` and 1043 is `varchar` (`select * from pg_type where oid in (23,1043)`)

The type modifier for the second column should indicate the qualifier on varchar, although I'm not quite sure why it's 24 rather than 20. Probably because that's the length of the varlena structure returned, which has a 32-bit length prepended. Anyway, that's how typmod works: if you do `select pg_catalog.format_type(1043, 24)`, you'll see that the output is `character varying(20)`. The [documentation for PQfmod](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN) says that the typmod interpretation is type-specific.